# Verifying a navigated to URL using Webdriverio and Chai

Tags: javascript, chai, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriverio v4 and chai to enter values into a  login form, click the login button and verify the navigated to URL:

```
describe('login form', function () { 
    it('should allow access with correct credentials', function () {
        LoginPage.open();
        LoginPage.username.setValue('name');
        LoginPage.companyCode.setValue('100');
        LoginPage.password.setValue('password');
        LoginPage.loginButton.click();

        expect(browser.getUrl()).to.equal('URL path');
    });    
});
```

the values are entered successfully and the expected URL is navigated to. However, browser.getURL() is returning the base URL rather than the new URL?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL may be retrieved too quickly. You may have to wait until the page has loaded the new page before getting the URL.

Could use something like with `waitUntil` and check the URL within the callback. Like so:

```
browser.waitUntil(function() {
    return browser.getUrl() === urlToCheck;
}, 5000);
```

See: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to resolve this by making the function asynchronous and adding await in front of the `browser.getURL()` function.

```
describe('login form', async () => { 
it('should allow access with correct credentials', function () {
    await LoginPage.open();
    await LoginPage.username.setValue('name');
    await LoginPage.companyCode.setValue('100');
    await LoginPage.password.setValue('password');
    await LoginPage.loginButton.click();

    await expect(await browser.getUrl()).to.equal('URL path');
    });    
});
```